# how can i assemble my components (kernel, initramfs, rootfs) into a single bootable image?

Tags: boot, boot-loader, bootable

I have created a compressed rootfs, kernel, and initramfs.  I have a syslinux configuration that boots my rootfs/kernel to RAM.  It works.

However, I'd like to have something like image1 which contains rootfs, kernel, initramfs and use a bootloader to boot image1.  Then I would make a fallback boot image (say, image2) and have the bootloader boot that if image1 failed.  I know I could have a fallback of some kind with my current configuration, but I'd prefer to have a complete assembled image instead of my piecewise method.

Ideally, I don't have to throw out my current SYSLINUX config, and can wrap it in another bootloader somehow?

My architecture is x86_64, if it matters.

Comment: It seems like I should be able to use u-boot, I'm trying something like this now: http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/RootFileSystemOnARamdisk

Comment: Or maybe I can still use SYSLINUX http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Common_Problems#mkdiskimage

Comment: You can compile an initramfs directly into the kernel.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.  I did not know that.  I still want to create a image which includes rootfs too, so I'm not sure that solves my problem.  The bootloader should be able to just refer to the image and some offset(s), instead of referring to kernel and rootfs.